# Make a custom taxonomy child of another custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

For a Wordpress plugin that I am currently developing (support ticket system) I have to map the following.
Each ticket is assigned to a project (1: 1 relationship).
Each project is in turn assigned to a customer (1: 1 relationship).
Thus, a customer can be assigned any number of projects (1: n relationship).
Also a Ticket could have multiple answers (like this question) which I think should also be a cpt.
I have already created the ticket as a custom post type.
Customers and project should be in my opinion taxonomies of the ticket.
The project should be assigned to the customer as parent taxonomy.
Therefore, I have set hierarchical = true for project.
But actually projects will be shown instead of customers in the parent dropdown(see screenshot below).
As far as I've read in Codex, I can customize the dropdown using the "[taxonomy_parent_dropdown_args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_parent_dropdown_args/)"-hook.
But I am not sure if there might be problems due to the different slugs.
Is this correct or is there a better way to archieve this?

[image]

Comment: One taxonomy can not be a child of another taxonomy. Only taxonomy terms can be used as child.

Comment: I tried to change the dropdown via the hook, which worked. But after saving the term, the table contained no more content lines so you can not change the term anymore. Only the number was still available and correct. Therefore, my question has clarified whether
the child term must belong to the same taxonomy as the parent term. Maybe I can save the relation as Term Meta. Then both taxonomies has to become non-hierarical.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
                $taxonomyName = "com_category";
                $parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));   

                foreach ($parent_terms as $pterm) {
                    $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => $pterm->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));
                    foreach ($terms as $term) {
                        echo '<div class="single_cat col-md-3">';
                        echo '<h3>'.$pterm->name.'</h3>'; 
                        echo "<ul>";
                        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>'; 
                        echo "</ul>";
                        echo '</div>'; 
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This will maybe work on the frontend but not on the taxonomy edit screen.
On this I have to alter the args for the dropdown via the ""taxonomy_parent_dropdown_args"" hook.

Comment: You can make a list of custom child category list under the parent

Comment: Yes, but the child category has to be from the same type as the parent.
So if I name the parent category mjm_customer all children have to be from the type mjm_customer. But the childrens should have a own category type of mjm_projects. I've already dive into code @see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56356697/make-a-custom-taxonomy-child-of-another-custom-taxonomy/56357037#99327380) my comment from May 29 at 13:42 [/link> and see that this is not possible. So I wil try to store it as term metas.